# Как задать параметры ядра при загрузке системы?

Tags: linux, dump

Настраиваю генерацию core dump файлов. Сделал следующее:

1. Прописал в файл /etc/security/limits.conf

   ```
   soft    core            unlimited
   ```

   Чтобы каждый раз при перезагрузке не вводить ulimit -c unlimited.
2. Прописал в файл /etc/sysctl.conf

   ```
   kernel.core_pattern = /tmp/core-%e-%s-%u-%g-%p-%t
   fs.suid_dumpable = 2 
   kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
   ```

Но данные параметры не принимаются пока не введешь sysctrl -p.
Вопрос: надо писать скрипт, который каждый раз при загрузке будет делать sysctrl -p или есть обходной путь, как-нибудь настроить ядро?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Надо писать скрипт, который каждый раз при загрузке будет делать `sysctrl -p`?

Самостоятельно не надо. Во всех маломальски распространённых дистрибутивах `/sbin/sysctl --system` выполняется одним из скриптов инициализации. Если ты создаёшь свой дистрибутив с нуля, то это, конечно, надо учесть.

> есть обходной путь, как-нибудь настроить ядро?

На Linux всё что делает `sysctl` это записывает соответствующие значения в файлы в каталоге `/proc/sys/`. То же самое можно сделать вручную, т.е. для изменения, например, `fs.suid_dumpable = 2` можно сделать:

```
echo 2 >/proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
```

Само собой, эти параметры будут в действии только до перезагрузки.

Также некоторые параметры можно установить во время загрузки ядра. Например, передача в командную строку ядра `panic=5` аналогична установке параметра `kernel.panic`. Но список этих параметров неполон и исключительно ситуативен.

Comment: гмм... мне даже любопытно стало, за что минус...

Comment: без понятия, кому-то не понравилось.

Comment: То есть надо пересобрать ядро с учетом данных параметров?

Comment: @Pure_love, к чему это относится/где я что-то подобное написал? и, вероятней всего, — «нет»...